# Specific Array Props to Specific Children [React]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am rendering children as an object in a component, and I have an array of results, and the number of children is equal to the number of results.  I am currently passing ALL of the results to each child, and I'm trying to change that so a different single result is passed to each child.  For example, pass child[0] the results[0] value, pass child[1] the results[1] value, etc.

I'm currently using the below code block to pass all of the results to each child:

```
    {React.Children.map(
      children,
      child => React.cloneElement(child, { results }),
    )}
```

I'm pretty certain I need to loop through the children and then the results (or vice versa), but I'm struggling with the proper syntax.  If anyone has any tips I'd greatly appreciate them, but if I figure this out before then I'll be certain to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the map's index (`i`):

```
{React.Children.map(
  children,
  (child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, { result: results[i] })
)}
```

**Example:**

```js
const results = [1, 2, 3];

const Child = ({ result }) => <div>{ result }</div>

const Parent = ({ result, children }) => (
  <div>
  {React.Children.map(
    children,
    (child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, { result: results[i] })
  )}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent results={results}>
    <Child />
    <Child />
    <Child />
  </Parent>,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```